# how to declare a local variable of type number inside a typescript function?

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my code and the error i am getting.

```
quicksort(low:number,high:number){
if(low<high){

let pi=this.partition(low,high); 
this.quicksort(low,pi-1);
}
}
partition(low:number,high:number){
/* my partition logic*/
}
```

[image: error img]

What is it that i have to do ? Is it not possible to declare local variables of a number type in typescript?

Comment: set number as a return datatype for partition(low, high) function

Comment: or better implement the partition function. right now it returns undefined, hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a return-type to you partition-funtion:

```
partition(low:number,high:number): number {
    /* my partition logic*/
}
```

Comment: While this is good practice, it's worth noting that it's not always necessary.
```function x(){
 return Math.random();
}``` , TS usually catches on with what you had in mind.

Comment: Using (strict) types helps finding errors early and makes your programm more stable

Comment: @matek997 you can cast it if needed

Comment: or better implement the `partition` function. right now it returns undefined, hence the error